# Decrypt PHP openssl_seal output with JS Forge

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, php-openssl, forge

I am trying to decrypt my openssl_seal stored values.
My PHP code:

```
public static function multiEncrypt( string $data, array $publicKeys ) : ?array
{
    foreach ($publicKeys as $cert)
    {
        if (false === openssl_get_publickey( $cert )) {
            Log::getInstance()->error('multiEncrypt : invalid pubkey ; ' . openssl_error_string());
            return null;
        }
    }

    $encryptedData = null;
    $encryptedKeys = [];
    $initVector = self::getInitVector( self::SEAL_CIPHER );

    $result = openssl_seal(
        $data,
        $encryptedData,
        $encryptedKeys,
        $publicKeys,
        self::SEAL_CIPHER,
        $initVector
    );

    if (false === $result)
        return null;

    $encodedData = base64_encode( $encryptedData );
    $encodedKeys = [];
    foreach ($encryptedKeys as $key) {
        $encodedKeys[] = base64_encode($key);
    }

    return [
        'keys' => $encodedKeys,
        'data' => $encodedData
    ];
}
```

and my client-side code:

```
    function decrypt(privkey, blob, key)
    {
        var byteKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(privkey);
        var usrPubKey = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(publicKey);
        //var genPubKey = forge.pki.rsa.setPublicKey(byteKey.n, byteKey.e);

        /*if (usrPubKey !== genPubKey) {
            error('Your private key does not match the public key we have of you.');
            return;
        }*/

        console.log('Decoding key..');
        var decodedKey = atob(key);
        console.log('Decrypting key..');
        var contractUserKey = byteKey.decrypt(decodedKey);

        console.log(contractUserKey);

        console.log(contractUserKey.decrypt(blob));
}
```

However I keep getting 'forge.min.js:4068 Uncaught Error: Encryption block is invalid.'. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Maybe because the private key doesn't match the public key used to encrypt? or data was encoded improperly ... ?

Comment: I replaced my public & private and it seems to now report: Uncaught Error: Encryption block is invalid. See https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/513